# Cannot find patches for WebLogic 12.1.2?

Tags: oracle, weblogic

This doc

http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-middleware-069163.pdf

says WebLogic 12.1.2 has "Premier Support" until Dec 2017.

Still, according to

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/security-advisory/cpuapr2017-3236618.html?elq_mid=76097&sh=0807222126131215260608081213150711063419&cmid=WWMK11063961MPP005C478

all of the weblogic CVE's mentioned in the latest Critical-Patch April 2017

```
  CVE-2017-5638
  CVE-2016-1181
  CVE-2017-3506
  CVE-2017-3531
```

have patches for WLS 12.1.3, but none for 12.1.2.

Looking at the nature of the CVE's, I think this does not make sense.
And this was the same for last Oracle CPU in January --- no updates for 12.1.2.

Anyone can clarify this situation?

Is 12.1.2 still supported?  If so, why no patches?

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The first doc you linked you refers to 12.1.x, not specifically 12.1.2. 12.1.3 is the terminal release for 12.1.x. If you have access to My Oracle Support, look at doc ID 1933372.1. (I don't think I'm allowed to reproduce what that says here, but it's off-topic anyway really...)

Comment: hmmm... my sloppy reading, got it --- thanks!